# how to use breakpoint in mydll.dll using python3 and pythonnet

Tags: c#, python-3.6, python.net

I have function imported from a DLL file using pythonnet:

I need to trace my function(in a C# DLL) with Python.

Answer (score 0):

you can hook a Visual Studio debugger to python.exe which runs your dll